# Raising one of the indexes of the product of two tensors

Tags: tensors

A text that I am studying appears to have raised the index of the product of tensors as shown below

$$g^{MN} U_{M;K}\;U_{N;L} = U_{M;K}\;U^M_{\;\;;L}$$

where

$$ U_{M;K} = \frac{\partial U_M}{\partial X_K} \;\;\;\text{and} \;\;\; U^M_{\;\;;L} = \frac{\partial U^M}{\partial X_L}$$

What is the rule for raising the index here? Why was the index of $U_{M;K}$ raised and not $U_{N;L}$? Is it simply due to "proximity", or is $U_{M;K}$ raised to $U^N_{\;\;;K}$ before converting $N$ to $M$, on account of $g^{MN}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.On one hand
$$ g^{MN}U_{M;K}U_{N;L} = U_{M;K}(g^{MN}U_{N;L}) = U_{M;K}U^M_{;L}
$$
On the other hand,
$$ g^{MN}U_{M;K}U_{N;L} = (g^{MN}U_{M;K})U_{N;L} =U^N_{;K}U_{N;L} = U^M_{;K}U_{M;L} $$

Answer (score 0):

From left to right, the index $M$ in $U^M_{\quad;L}$ was *lowered*, not raised. In other words, $U^M_{\quad; L} = g^{MN}U_{N;L}$ and, of course, this is allowed because the metric tensor is covariantly constant (i.e., parallel, so that covariant derivatives commute with the process of raising and lowering indices). The term $U_{M;K}$ is just there being contracted against the above and does not directly participate in this discussion.

More explicitly, once you accept that $U^M_{\quad; L} = g^{MN}U_{N;L}$, you hit both sides of that with $U_{M;K}$ to get $U_{M;K} U^M_{\quad;L} = g^{MN}U_{M;K} U_{N;L}$, noting that on the right side of the equality we actually have a *double* sum.

Comment: Apologies. The equation was stated the wrong way round. I have swapped the LHS and RHS.